# WORDPRESS: Slide on every page

Tags: wordpress

I really don't code much (more like... none), I'm personalizing a wordpress and have a few problems that cannot resolve, one of them is that I have a fixed header that shows on every page, below that is a slider that only shows on the index, I need this to  be showing as a part of the header on every page, I want the slider to take the screen from side to side, now is just centered. I'm using LayerSliderWP plugin.

Thanks to everybody for you help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check where your slider is called.

Do you call it in a post with a shortcode like `[slider]` or is it in your template (header.php/index.php/page.php) like `<?php slider(1); ?>`
or `<?php do_shortcode("[slider]"); ?>`?

Maybe your call is only on the index.php file, it only appears on your front page. If you place it on the page.php, it appears on every page (not post!). Place the code on your header.php and it appears on every site/post whatever.

A piece of code would be helpfull.

~ Neme

Comment: I can't find that code anywhere. Its a plunggin and it sais Homepage Slider. The site is http://eda.132.myftpupload.com/ Thank for all your help @Neme